Implementing Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications package in an Unity project
Has anyone had success with adding the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications package to their Unity project?
I have been unsuccessful in implementing Microsoft Windows Local Toast Notification. As far as I know, it cannot be implemented properly in Unity, because Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications requires .NET 6 to work properly [for example Show()' needs it ,as it was mentioned in Microsoft Docs '], and Unity doesn't support it (the latest version supported is .NET 4). I've encountered errors indicating compatibility or missing problems. I assume that's why I’m facing this issue. It would be great if someone could help me clarify this and correct me if I've come to the wrong conclusion [about unity supported .NET version and so on]
PS: I extracted required DLLs by adding it to a C# project and changed that project TFM to .net6. Then I added them to Assets\Plugins\metro. The errors in unity console regarding to missing Functions and classes were gone but I still had errors that showed combability or missing errors. (I have added all)

Assembly Assets/Plugins/metro/UWP/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll will not be loaded due to errors:


Unable to resolve reference
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe. Is the assembly missing or
incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.


Assembly Assets/Plugins/metro/UWP/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.dll will not be loaded due to errors:


Reference has errors Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.


Assembly Assets/Plugins/metro/UWP/WinRT.Runtime.dll will not be loaded due to errors:


Unable to resolve reference System.Private.CoreLib. Is the
assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference System.Private.Uri. Is the assembly
missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference System.Security.Cryptography. Is the
assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.


well there is an asset on the store that looks like it does basically the same thing

It would be great if you provide me the name.
